# Why it works if I pass in a no-param function as callback expecting arguments?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been using this feature often: in `$.each(Ojbect, function)`, the function should expect for two arguments:

```
function (index, value) {...}
```

(per jQuery API document: [enter link description here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)). Most of the time, I define my a non-arg function. For-example, to print out the value only.

```
$.each([1,2,3], function(){
   console.log($(this);
});
```

So the $.each is accepting my no-arg func. This comes very handy in daily use.  But I have not found any official document that says this is OK. Just to be assured in mind, why such way works?

Comment: Note that it's jQuery that arranges for `this` to refer to each element in the array. If you're using the native `.forEach()` on the Array prototype, it does *not* do that, so your callback wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is how JavaScript function calls work. The number of arguments passed in to a function doesn't need to match the number of parameters in that function's definition. If there are less parameters than arguments (like in your example), the arguments will still be accessible, within the function, through the arguments array-like object. If there are more parameters than arguments, the variables without matching arguments will be `undefined`:

```
[
 function(){ console.log( arguments ); },     // ['foo', 'bar']
 function(x){ console.log( x, arguments ); }, // 'foo' ['foo', 'bar']
 function(x,y){ console.log( x, y ); },       // 'foo' 'bar'
 function(x,y,z){ console.log( x, y, z ); },  // 'foo' 'bar' undefined
].

// Call each function with two arguments: 'foo' and 'bar'
forEach( func => func( 'foo', 'bar' ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

Javascript is dynamic language with functions being first class citizens. Also function parameters are pretty much named aliases to positioned elements of `arguments` array-like object.

Given that you can define function with 0 arguments and still see values of parameters passed to it:

```
 (function() { console.log(arguments) } )('a',1,null, 'hey')

 >outputs: ["a", 1, null, "hey"]
```

Since js is dynamic language, there is no way for VM it enforce function arguments types or their number. And there is no way to specify types, for instance, either.

In Typescript there is better support for such things, which allow you to enforce type and number of parameters passed to the function, but what you observe is how javascript works.

Answer (score 0):

the callback arguments are optional, whether you set them or not entirely depends on you needs. If you have to access them in your callback scope, they should be there. In your console.log example it's ok to leave the args out. This results in a code which is shorter and easier to read (since there are no unused vars in it)

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, parameters need only be defined if they are used in a function.  If they are not used, then best practice recommends that they not be defined (in fact, Javascript code analysis tools such as jshint and jslint will report an error if parameters are defined but not used).

So, in answer to your question, it is perfectly fine to define your function as you have.